# CakePHP 3.x remove field from validation

Tags: cakephp-3.4

Is there a simple way to ignore a filed from being validated in CakePHP 3.x Controller?

I know two ways: First one is specify `fieldList`in patchEntity

second one is use `validate => myCustomValidater`

I do not want to use none of them, is there a simple method ?

Comment: you can simply comment or remove the `validationDefault` function from the desired Model.

Comment: @Rik.esh i have mentioned in 2nd method: `validate => myCustomValidater` means using custom validation not default one.

Comment: @Rik.esh i was asking for another method without using none of those that i mentioned, all i want is to remove one rule from one filed, eg removing `notEmpty ` rule from a field named `myfield`.
means i want to validate my data in two cases: 1st one using validation that validate `myfield` field if user choosed something, else ignore that field and remove its validation rules.